# Codeigniter setup multiple environment

Tags: codeigniter, development-environment

I am about to make my website goes live, but I face a problem that after uploading the entire website to the server from local machine I will need to change the config file and upload to the server, but when I run in local machine I need to reset the config again. I was wondering is there any other way solve this issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: yes leave `base_url` blank `$config['base_url'] = "";`

Comment: @PraveenKumar not recommended to leave it blank if your using CI3 versions It says in Ci3 config `WARNING: You MUST set this value!`

Comment: Have you changed configuration? Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about changing your base url all the time.

First place this code below on index.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {

    $base_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
    $base_url .= '://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

} else {

    $base_url = 'http://localhost/';

}

define('HTTP_SERVER', $base_url);

unset($base_url);
```

And then in the config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = HTTP_SERVER;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcuts for this. It means when your project is in local you have to setup local, when live you have to setup for live.

**Explanation and Tips**

- At the first time you code with project **in local**. So you have to
  **setup it correctly**. Cz its will be same on live hosting.
- So **first time** when you move all the **files and folders to Live Host**
  you **have to change, Database Configs, BaseUrl**..
- Then **if you edit some thing on your localhost** and you need to live
  the site, **Just move Controller, View, Model** folders only. ***Do not move
  the Config Folder(if any change do it manually)***.

> > So each and every time when you move the site, your config will be remain same at it is.

---

> > When you moving site to live, in root(**outside application folder**) edit **index.php** with following.

Change this to

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development'); # shows all the run time errors
```

This

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production'); # hide those and run the web smoothly, unless 500 or 404
```